# Select all checkboxes in table with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I am using checkboxes in table and I have a checkbox in tablehead.

What I am trying to accomplish is when I click the checkbox in head, all the checkboxes below in table rows should be checked..

Here is my HTML:

```
            <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
        <div class="content top">
          <table id="datatable_example" class="responsive table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0; ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:0px; padding-right:0px;" class="no_sort"> <label class="checkbox ">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="checkAll" class="select_all">
                  </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width:200px;" class="no_sort"> Institue </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="no_sort"> Education </th>
                <th style="width:300px;" class="no_sort"> Description </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Started </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Completion </th>
                <th class="ms no_sort "> Actions </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php echo $educations ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="row-fluid control-group">
            <div class="pull-left span6 " action="#">
              <div>


                <div class="controls inline input-large pull-left">                    
                  <select name="bulkaction" data-placeholder="Bulk actions: " class="chzn-select " id="default-select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="delete">Delete</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submitbulkaction" class="btn btn-inverse inline">Apply</button></form>
```

Here is php variable $education which is used in the table..

```
$educations .= "<tr>
                <td><label class=\"checkbox\">
                    <input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"chkboxes\" name=\"ids[]\" value=\"$education_id\">
                  </label></td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $institue_name</td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $education_name</td>
                    <td>$education_desc</td>
                <td>$education_started</td>
                <td>$education_ended</td>
                <td class=\"ms\">
                <div class=\"btn-group1\"> 
                <a href=\"education-edit.php?id=$education_id\" class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"left\" data-original-title=\" edit \">
                <i class=\"gicon-edit\"></i></a> 
                <a class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"View\">
                <i class=\"gicon-eye-open\"></i>
                </a> 
                <a class=\"btn  btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" data-original-title=\"Remove\"><i class=\"gicon-remove \"></i></a> 
                </div>
                </td>
              </tr>";
```

The Jquery behind I am trying to set..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $('.chkboxes').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});
    </script>
```

Please tell me what is it I am doing wrong here, and how to fix the problem?

I looked in to other questions too posted about same issue checkboxes an most of them got solved, but still still when I apply the same code I don't get the result I want.

---

Update: I fixed the class name error as you all mentioned, Thank you,
but now its some strange problem came up.
I mean now it works but it don't works just like I click on checkbox and all checkboxes get selected on the go.. I had to refresh the page then all checkboxes will be selected?
Whats up with that issue?
Why I do need to refresh the page for that event to happen?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: From what I'm seeing you're trying to use `.checkboxes` and in your PHP code you're using `.chkboxes`

Comment: @MarcusRecck
Thankyou, i updated my error, but now new issue came up.
When i click the checkbox to selectAll it is not selected at that moment but when i click the reload button then all checkboxes are selected cuz of the checkbox i clicked before the refreshing of the Page.

Comment: Try implementing one of the sample codes in the answers section.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $('#datatable_example .chkboxes').prop('checked', true);
        // $('#datatable_example input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see the update sir,
I fixed the class name error. 
also even i tried copy pasting your Jquery.

it works, but in order to make it work i need to refresh the page. it is a strange problem i am getting now.
i mean if i click the checkAll checkbox the rest of the checkboxes are not selected at that instant but when i refresh the page, all the other checkboxes gets selected cuz of i selected the the checkAll before refreshing the page.
This is strange Problem???

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to check a class called checkbox, not the actual checkboxes. Identify the checkbox by its type attribute -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $('#datatable_example input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see the update sir,
I fixed the class name error. 
also even i tried copy pasting your Jquery.

it works, but in order to make it work i need to refresh the page. it is a strange problem i am getting now.
i mean if i click the checkAll checkbox the rest of the checkboxes are not selected at that instant but when i refresh the page, all the other checkboxes gets selected cuz of i selected the the checkAll before refreshing the page.
This is strange Problem???

Comment: Do all of the checkboxes have the same ID? If so, you need to fix that.

Comment: No Sir,
All the checkboxes do not have same id's.
Thou they have same names. I haven't used id attribute for the checkboxes, only used id attribute for the main checkbox which should checkall the other checkboxes.

Comment: Is there somewhere that we can see the more complete markup? There has to be something else going on here.

Comment: Sir, here is my full code for educations.php and footer.php
footer.php includes all the jquery files and scripts.
Educations.php http://tny.cz/ee92381e
Footer.php http://tny.cz/00e45039

I can attach files, but i dont know where to attach files now?

Comment: In that example there is only one checkbox (#checkAll), so I cannot perform the action that you desire because I cannot see any other checkboxes in the example. Can you post the actual HTML output by all of the PHP, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chkboxes').attr('checked','checked');
```

The class is different.

Also consider using [heredocs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) or ending the PHP with `?>` and beginning again after your HTML content with `<?php` before closing the block.

Answer (score 0):

you given class as `class=\"chkboxes\"`

and in jquery you given

```
  $('.checkboxes').attr('checked','checked');
```

correct it

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkAll').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('fieldset:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
</script>
```

You only need to add `fieldset` tag after `<form>` and closed before `</form>`, but only the checkboxes between fieldset tags will be checked.

http://briancray.com/posts/check-all-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it...

`$("#buttonSelectAll").click(function () {
           if($("#Table").find('input:checkbox:first').attr("checked")==="checked")
                    $('#Table input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
                else
                    $('#Table input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            });`

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple table use this

$('th input:checkbox').click(function(e) {

var table = $(e.target).closest('table');
$('td input:checkbox', table).attr('checked', e.target.checked);

});

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkAll').click(function () {
        $('#datatable_example').find('.chkboxes').prop('checked', true);
        });
});
```